# How to draw a TikZ diagram that does not occupy space

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to TikZ and I have a trivial question. How to draw a borderless diagram? In other words, I need something that does not displace the text. Similar to the effect achieved with a regular LaTeX picture with {0,0} for width and height.
Here is a minimal example of what I need the diagram to look like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
  \put(0,3){\vector(1,0){60}}
\end{picture}
Picture
\tikz{\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0:80pt);}
TikZ
\end{document}
```

This results in the following:

[example http://ubuntuone.com/1Kgnezgx4gUSZ9sgJIcjJR](http://ubuntuone.com/1Kgnezgx4gUSZ9sgJIcjJR)

I would like the vector (and the environment in general) of TikZ to be over the word and not displace it. Similar to the one with Picture. I feel there's a straightforward solution for this, but I can't seem to find it.

Thank you

Comment: Use the option `overlay`. BTW: welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino overlay is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `overlay` option:

```
\tikz[overlay]{\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0:80pt);}
```

If you want to raise the error the `baseline` option might help:

```
\tikz[overlay,baseline=-0.8ex]{\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0:80pt);}
```

Together with `overlay` the `remember picture` option offers some nice features, like drawing at an absolute position of the current page

```
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw (current page.center) circle [radius=10mm];}
```

(where `current page` has the anchors of a rectangular `node`) or connecting two pictures

```
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(first.base)]{\node [blue] (first) {First Node};}
Some regular Text her in this line.

A new paragraph and more text, ending with a
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(second.base)]{\node [blue] (second) {second Node};}.

\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw [blue,<->] (first) to[bend left] (second);}
```

[image: connecting pictures]

Comment: Beware of [node spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95649/13304): often is not fine within text.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
  \put(0,3){\vector(1,0){60}}
\end{picture}
Picture

\makebox(0,0){\put(0,3){\vector(1,0){60}}}
Picture

\makebox[0pt][l]{\tikz\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0:80pt);}
TikZ

\tikz\draw [overlay,->] (0,0) -- (0:80pt);
TikZ
\end{document}
```