# Remove whitespace around tikz picture in running text

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I'm trying to draw a star in text brackets using tikz and I can't figure out how to remove the large white space to the left and right. The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\yellowstar}{
\tikzstyle{scorestars}=[star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.5, draw,inner sep=1.3pt,anchor=outer point 3]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \draw (0,0) node[name=star,scorestars,fill=yellow]  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
Hello (\yellowstar).
\end{document}
```

The code is based on this: [Drawing stars/similar with Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11390/drawing-stars-similar-with-tikz)

This suggestion of adding a %-sign after "(" and putting \yellowstar on the next line doesn't work: [Reduce white space around TikZ picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95649/reduce-white-space-around-tikz-picture)

Comment: Related: [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have end of line spaces. To remove them add few `%` marks at the end of lines like I did.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\yellowstar}{%
\tikzstyle{scorestars}=[star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.5, draw,inner sep=1.3pt,anchor=outer point 3]%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \draw (0,0) node[name=star,scorestars,fill=yellow]  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
Hello (\yellowstar).
\end{document}
```

Or you can simply push the style commands inside the TikZ picture with the preferred syntax `/.` handles. See [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles) for more details. Then the macro definition becomes

```
\newcommand{\yellowstar}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,
          scorestars/.style={star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.5,
                             draw,inner sep=1.3pt,anchor=outer point 3}
 ]
    \draw (0,0) node[name=star,scorestars,fill=yellow]  {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Then you have no whitespace seen by TeX since TikZ gobbles the spurious whitespace within its own environment.

Comment: I can confirm that adding the 3 %-signs in the places you suggest to remove the end-of-line spaces works. Thank you very much!