# Aligning multiple figures/tikzpicture vertically and horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I'm trying to align four figures vertically and horizontally. But I couldn't get it right in spite of repeated tweaks.

Can someone help me out?

Here is a MWE -- there are no errors, but the figures don't come out scaled properly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{llncs}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 \pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{plain}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{width=2in}
\begin{minipage}[t][4em][s]{.5\textwidth}
\subfloat[First]{
%\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]

\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};


\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[->] (2) -- (3);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
\draw[->] (4) -- (5);
%\draw (8) -- (7);
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);

\end{tikzpicture}
%\label{fig:sto}
} %%\qquad
%
%\bigskip
%
\subfloat[Second]{
\label{fig:st}
%\begin{subfgure}[b]{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]

\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};


\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (2) to[out=-100,in=-150] (1);
%\draw (3) -- (2);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (4) to[out=-100,in=-150] (3);
%\draw (5) -- (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (2) to[out=-250,in=-350] (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (3) to[out=100,in=150] (1);    
%\draw (8) -- (7);
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (6) to[out=-100,in=-150] (5);


\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t][4em][s]{0.5\textwidth}
\subfloat[Third]{
%\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
%\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]

\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};


\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[->] (2) -- (3);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
\draw[->] (4) -- (5);
%\draw (8) -- (7);
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);


\end{tikzpicture}
} %%\qquad
%
\subfloat[Fourth]{
\label{fig:ts}
%\begin{subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]

\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};


\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (4) to[out=-100,in=-150] (1);
%\draw (3) -- (2);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (5) to[out=100,in=150] (1);
%\draw (5) -- (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (2) to[out=100,in=150] (5);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (4) to[out=-100,in=-160] (2);  
%\draw (8) -- (7);
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (6) to[out=100,in=150] (3);

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be good if you add an image of the result so that people can see it directly.

Comment: If you only get a small unwanted space, try to add a `%` directly after `{` and `}` when they are at the end of a line, like `\subfloat[Fourth]{`. Otherwise the line break there is taken as a space. This is explained further in [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453). Not sure if this happens here, because I don't know the inner context of `\subfloat`.

Comment: You're using curved lines, therefore the final bounding box of your second and fourth figures are not correct. This produces incorrect alignments. Take a look at [Bounding box is larger than expected when drawing a curved path](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43621/1952) and [Is there a way to control whitespace around a TikZ picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57484/1952)

Comment: Another problem is figure size. Altough you're using `minipage`, your figures don't fit in it and they are not scaled. If you want to scale them use `adjustbox`, `resizebox` or just draw being sure that they have its correct size to fit where you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** 
**Version 2: New**

1. Define a bounding box with:
   `\path[use as bounding box] (\xA,\yA ) rectangle (\xB,\yB);`
   ... inside each figure. See [15.8 Establishing a Bounding Box,(p.176)](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).  The `x`- and `y`-values are defined with `\def` (`\def\xA{-0.8}, \def\yA{-1.6},\def\xB{12.4},\def\yB{1.6}`). They should fit the biggest figure. To find the best fitting you could set `\drawORnot` to `1` and move the bounding box in an good position.
2. I added the option to draw the bounding box with `\drawboundingbox[<color>]{\drawORnot}` to each figure. It will be drawn only if `\drawORnot` is `1`, therefor i used `\ifthenelse`.

   `\drawORnot`= 1 -> bounding box on

   `\drawORnot` = 2-> bounding box off)
3. Scaling and simplification is the same (with `resizebox` ...) , see version 1 below.
   [image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2cm]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\def\xA{-0.8}
\def\yA{-1.6}
\def\xB{12.4}
\def\yB{1.6}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\drawORnot{1}% 1-> bounding box on; else -> bounding box off
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\drawboundingbox}[2][red]{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{1}}
    {
    \draw [#1] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    }
    {
    %FALSE
    }%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\subfloat[AAAA]{\label{fig:AAAA}
\resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]
\path[use as bounding box] (\xA,\yA ) rectangle (\xB,\yB);
\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};
\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[->] (2) -- (3);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
\draw[->] (4) -- (5);
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);
\drawboundingbox[green]{\drawORnot}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[BBBB]{\label{fig:BBBB}
\resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]
\path[use as bounding box] (\xA,\yA ) rectangle (\xB,\yB);
\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};
\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (2) to[out=-100,in=-150] (1);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (4) to[out=-100,in=-150] (3);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (2) to[out=-250,in=-350] (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (3) to[out=100,in=150] (1);    
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (6) to[out=-100,in=-150] (5);
\drawboundingbox[blue]{\drawORnot}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[CCCC]{\label{fig:CCCC}
\resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]
\path[use as bounding box] (\xA,\yA ) rectangle (\xB,\yB);
\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};
\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[->] (2) -- (3);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
\draw[->] (4) -- (5);
%%\draw (8) -- (7);
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);
\drawboundingbox[yellow]{\drawORnot}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[DDDD]{\label{fig:DDDD}
\resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]
\path[use as bounding box] (\xA,\yA ) rectangle (\xB,\yB);
\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};
\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (4) to[out=-100,in=-150] (1);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (2) to[out=100,in=150] (5);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (4) to[out=-100,in=-160] (2);  
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (6) to[out=100,in=150] (3);
\drawboundingbox[black]{\drawORnot}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\hfill 
\caption{Aligning figures in a table with colored bounding boxes (optional).}\label{fig:FIGone}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

---

**Version 1:**

## 1. The problem is the different bounding box/ size of your different `tikzpicture`.

So i use an invisible `\path` to get the same size of very picture. The dimensions are a first try and maybe could be optimized the same way. So you could add for example:

`\path[step=1.0,black,thin,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] (-3,-3) grid (12,3);`

... to every `tikzpicture`. If you replace `\path` with `\draw` you can see the dimensions.

## 2. Scaling

With `\resizebox{<horizontal size>}{<vertical size>}{...}` (see: [4.3.2 Scaling to a requested size](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), p.8)  you could set the horizontal and vertical size of the `tikzpicture`. If you want the `tikzpicture` to be scaled proportionally, you can give one of the sizes and put `!` in the other. I used `6.5cm`horizontal.

## 3 Simplify

I removed some packages to get a small MWE and changed the documentclass to article. It works also with `llncs` (download:[llncs.cls](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs.cls)).

```
\resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
....
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

**Aligned four figures:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\subfloat[AAAA]{\label{fig:AAAA}
\resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]
\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};
\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[->] (2) -- (3);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
\draw[->] (4) -- (5);
%%\draw (8) -- (7);
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);
\path[step=1.0,black,thin,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] (-3,-3) grid (12,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[BBBB]{\label{fig:BBBB}
\resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]
\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};
\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (2) to[out=-100,in=-150] (1);
%%\draw (3) -- (2);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (4) to[out=-100,in=-150] (3);
%%\draw (5) -- (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (2) to[out=-250,in=-350] (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (3) to[out=100,in=150] (1);    
%%\draw (8) -- (7);
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (6) to[out=-100,in=-150] (5);
\path[step=1.0,black,thin,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] (-3,-3) grid (12,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[CCCC]{\label{fig:CCCC}
\resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]
\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};
\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[->] (2) -- (3);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
\draw[->] (4) -- (5);
%%\draw (8) -- (7);
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);
\path[step=1.0,black,thin,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] (-3,-3) grid (12,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[DDDD]{\label{fig:DDDD}
\resizebox{6.5cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw, scale=1.0, fill=gray!50}, scale=1.0, rotate = 180, xscale = -1]
\node (1) at (0, 0) {$a$};
\node (2) at (3.0, 0) {$t$};
\node (3) at (4.5, 0) {$t'$};
\node (4) at (7.5, 0) {$s'$};
\node (5) at (9.0, 0) {$s$};
\node (6) at (12.0, 0) {$b$};
\draw[->] (1) -- (2);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (4) to[out=-100,in=-150] (1);
%%\draw (3) -- (2);
\draw[->] (3) -- (4);
%\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (5) to[out=100,in=150] (1);
%%\draw (5) -- (4);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (2) to[out=100,in=150] (5);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (4) to[out=-100,in=-160] (2);  
%%\draw (8) -- (7);
\draw[->] (5) -- (6);
\draw[thick, dashed, ->] (6) to[out=100,in=150] (3);
\path[step=1.0,black,thin,xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] (-3,-3) grid (12,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}%
\hfill 
\caption{Aligning figures in a table}\label{fig:FIGone}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have added an (similar) alternative solution with `\path[use as bounding box]`.