# Aligning figures in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code for a tikz figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0, 85, 128}
\definecolor{colorforline}{RGB}{0, 26, 0}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2.8cm,thick]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=mycolor,draw=none,text=white]
    \tikzstyle{myarrows}=[line width=1mm,draw=mycolor,-triangle 45,postaction={draw, line width=3mm, shorten >=4mm, -}]
    \node[state] (A)  {$A$};
    \node[state]         (B) [below left of=A] {$B$};
    \node[state]         (C) [below right of=B] {$C$};
    \node[state]         (D) [below right of=A] {$D$};
    \node[state]         (E) [above right of=D,xshift=-1cm,yshift=0.6cm] {$E$};
    \node[state]         (F) [right of=C,yshift=0.3cm,xshift=1cm] {$F$};

    \path 
    (A) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {3} (B)
    (B) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {5} (C)
    (C) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {2} (D)
    (D) edge[color=mycolor]     node {1} (E)
        edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {4} (A);
    \draw [myarrows] (5,-2) -- (6,-2) node [right]{$$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which results in the following output:
[image]

I want something that looks like the following figure:
[image]

Please note that in the last picture with sub-figures I am just reusing the code for the same tikz picture that I added above. So please use that.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! - Related or duplicat?:[Aligning multiple figures/tikzpicture vertically and horizontally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401246/124842)

Comment: my figure needed more tweaking than the one mentioned as duplicate. that question has two figures in a row and still the figure sizes are smaller. my problem had three images in a row and I managed to make it more clearer than the duplicate question

Comment: I think your rescalebox is just a little bit smaller (4 instead of 6.5 cm widht)....! Or do you diagree with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0, 85, 128}
\definecolor{colorforline}{RGB}{0, 26, 0}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\subfloat[AAAA]{\label{fig:AAAA}
\resizebox{4cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2.8cm,thick]
\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=mycolor,draw=none,text=white]
\tikzstyle{myarrows}=[line width=1mm,draw=mycolor,-triangle 45,postaction={draw, line width=3mm, shorten >=4mm, -}]
\node[state] (A)  {$A$};
\node[state]         (B) [below left of=A] {$B$};
\node[state]         (C) [below right of=B] {$C$};
\node[state]         (D) [below right of=A] {$D$};
\node[state]         (E) [above right of=D,xshift=-1cm,yshift=0.6cm] {$E$};
\node[state]         (F) [right of=C,yshift=0.3cm,xshift=1cm] {$F$};

\path 
(A) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {3} (B)
(B) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {5} (C)
(C) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {2} (D)
(D) edge[color=mycolor]     node {1} (E)
edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {4} (A);
\draw [myarrows] (5,-2) -- (6,-2) node [right]{$$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[BBBB]{\label{fig:BBBB}
\resizebox{4cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2.8cm,thick]
\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=mycolor,draw=none,text=white]
\tikzstyle{myarrows}=[line width=1mm,draw=mycolor,-triangle 45,postaction={draw, line width=3mm, shorten >=4mm, -}]
\node[state] (A)  {$A$};
\node[state]         (B) [below left of=A] {$B$};
\node[state]         (C) [below right of=B] {$C$};
\node[state]         (D) [below right of=A] {$D$};
\node[state]         (E) [above right of=D,xshift=-1cm,yshift=0.6cm] {$E$};
\node[state]         (F) [right of=C,yshift=0.3cm,xshift=1cm] {$F$};

\path 
(A) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {3} (B)
(B) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {5} (C)
(C) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {2} (D)
(D) edge[color=mycolor]     node {1} (E)
edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {4} (A);
\draw [myarrows] (5,-2) -- (6,-2) node [right]{$$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[CCCC]{\label{fig:CCCC}
\resizebox{3.4cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2.8cm,thick]
\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=mycolor,draw=none,text=white]
\tikzstyle{myarrows}=[line width=1mm,draw=mycolor,-triangle 45,postaction={draw, line width=3mm, shorten >=4mm, -}]
\node[state] (A)  {$A$};
\node[state]         (B) [below left of=A] {$B$};
\node[state]         (C) [below right of=B] {$C$};
\node[state]         (D) [below right of=A] {$D$};
\node[state]         (E) [above right of=D,xshift=-1cm,yshift=0.6cm] {$E$};
\node[state]         (F) [right of=C,yshift=0.3cm,xshift=1cm] {$F$};

\path 
(A) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {3} (B)
(B) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {5} (C)
(C) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {2} (D)
(D) edge[color=mycolor]     node {1} (E)
edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {4} (A);
%\draw [myarrows] (5,-2) -- (6,-2) node [right]{$$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[DDDD]{\label{fig:DDDD}
\resizebox{4cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2.8cm,thick]
\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=mycolor,draw=none,text=white]
\tikzstyle{myarrows}=[line width=1mm,draw=mycolor,-triangle 45,postaction={draw, line width=3mm, shorten >=4mm, -}]
\node[state] (A)  {$A$};
\node[state]         (B) [below left of=A] {$B$};
\node[state]         (C) [below right of=B] {$C$};
\node[state]         (D) [below right of=A] {$D$};
\node[state]         (E) [above right of=D,xshift=-1cm,yshift=0.6cm] {$E$};
\node[state]         (F) [right of=C,yshift=0.3cm,xshift=1cm] {$F$};

\path 
(A) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {3} (B)
(B) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {5} (C)
(C) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {2} (D)
(D) edge[color=mycolor]     node {1} (E)
edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {4} (A);
\draw [myarrows] (5,-2) -- (6,-2) node [right]{$$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[DDDD]{\label{fig:DDDD}
    \resizebox{4cm}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2.8cm,thick]
        \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=mycolor,draw=none,text=white]
        \tikzstyle{myarrows}=[line width=1mm,draw=mycolor,-triangle 45,postaction={draw, line width=3mm, shorten >=4mm, -}]
        \node[state] (A)  {$A$};
        \node[state]         (B) [below left of=A] {$B$};
        \node[state]         (C) [below right of=B] {$C$};
        \node[state]         (D) [below right of=A] {$D$};
        \node[state]         (E) [above right of=D,xshift=-1cm,yshift=0.6cm] {$E$};
        \node[state]         (F) [right of=C,yshift=0.3cm,xshift=1cm] {$F$};

        \path 
        (A) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {3} (B)
        (B) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {5} (C)
        (C) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {2} (D)
        (D) edge[color=mycolor]     node {1} (E)
        edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {4} (A);
        \draw [myarrows] (5,-2) -- (6,-2) node [right]{$$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}%
\hfill 
\subfloat[DDDD]{\label{fig:DDDD}
    \resizebox{3.4cm}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2.8cm,thick]
        \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=mycolor,draw=none,text=white]
        \tikzstyle{myarrows}=[line width=1mm,draw=mycolor,-triangle 45,postaction={draw, line width=3mm, shorten >=4mm, -}]
        \node[state] (A)  {$A$};
        \node[state]         (B) [below left of=A] {$B$};
        \node[state]         (C) [below right of=B] {$C$};
        \node[state]         (D) [below right of=A] {$D$};
        \node[state]         (E) [above right of=D,xshift=-1cm,yshift=0.6cm] {$E$};
        \node[state]         (F) [right of=C,yshift=0.3cm,xshift=1cm] {$F$};

        \path 
        (A) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {3} (B)
        (B) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {5} (C)
        (C) edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {2} (D)
        (D) edge[color=mycolor]     node {1} (E)
        edge[above,color=mycolor]     node {4} (A);
%       \draw [myarrows] (5,-2) -- (6,-2) node [right]{$$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}%
\hfill 

\caption{Aligning figures in a table}\label{fig:FIGone}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Does this:
[image]