# Removing whitespace on the left side of a tikzpicture to align it

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, bounding-box

There's a lot of whitespace on the left of the figure drawn by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{%
  xbar%
  ,/tikz/font=\footnotesize\sffamily\color{gray!70}

}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=false]{%
  40, beides (sowohl Schul- als auch Massnahmetraeger)
  12.5, Massnahmetraeger
  53.8, Schultraeger
}{\fremdbewirtschaftung}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=false]{%
  20, beides (sowohl Schul- als auch Massnahmetraeger)
  6.3, Massnahmetraeger
  0, Schultraeger
}{\eigenbewirtschaftung}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=false]{%
  40, beides (sowohl Schul- als auch Massnahmetraeger)
  81.3, Massnahmetraeger
  30.8, Schultraeger
}{\kombination}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=false]{%
  0, beides (sowohl Schul- als auch Massnahmetraeger)
  0, Massnahmetraeger
  15.4, Schultraeger
}{\keinekenntnis}

%\noindent{}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \clip (-3.5,-1) rectangle (10.5, 5.75);
    \begin{axis}[%
      enlarge x limits=-0.1,% 
      enlarge y limits=0.2,% 
      xlabel={Prozent},%
      yticklabels from table={\kombination}{1},% 
      ytick=data,%
      yticklabel style={text width=5cm,align=right},% 
      nodes near coords,% 
      nodes near coords align={horizontal},% 
      legend style={%
        legend pos=outer north east%
        ,legend columns=1%
        ,draw=none%
        ,legend reversed=true% 
        ,legend cell align=left%
      }
      ]
      \addplot+ table [y expr=\coordindex, x=0]
      {\keinekenntnis};
      \addplot+ table [y expr=\coordindex, x=0]
      {\kombination};
      \addplot+ table [y expr=\coordindex, x=0]
      {\eigenbewirtschaftung};
      \addplot+ table [y expr=\coordindex, x=0]
      {\fremdbewirtschaftung};
      \legend{% 
        keine Kenntnis%
        ,Kombination%
        ,Eigenbewirtschaftung%
        ,Fremdbewirtschaftung%
      }
    \end{axis}
%    \draw [brown] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
%    \draw[gray,step=0.25] (-5.5,-1) grid (11, 6.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

There's a lot of whitespace on the left of the figure, that can be
removed by clipping the tikzpicture. But that's a very laborious way for
35 figures in my document.
\end{document}
```

[image: Whitespace around tikzpicture]

With the help of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57486/10682) I found a workaround by clipping the tikzpicture. Using `\clip (-3.5,-1) rectangle (10.5, 5.75);` reduces the whitespace and aligns it.

[image: Fixed whitespace around tikzpicture]

But it's a very laborious way to identify the clipping coordinates by drawing the grid and the bounding box. Is there a way to automate this task?

Furthermore it would be very handy if the tikzpicture had a maximal width of `\linewidth` without changing font sizes as it happens by scaling the figure.

Comment: Shorten `text width` in `ytikcklabel style`. And if you want to understand why, insert `draw` there and see the result before reducing `text width`.

Comment: @Ignasi: OMG. Awkward.

Comment: @Ignasi, `draw` also known as `troubleshoot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is due to

```
  yticklabel style={text width=5cm, align=right},%
```

It's effect can be seen with

```
  yticklabel style={draw, text width=5cm,align=right},%
```

which procudes:

[image]

If `text width` is shortened, left white space will be reduced.

As an example:

```
  yticklabel style={draw, text width=2.5cm, align=right},%
```

[image]