# A large (curved) arrow is causing my tikz-cd diagram to have too much space on one side. How can I fix this?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, diagrams, tikz-cd

I use `tikz-cd` to draw commutative diagrams, and recently needed to draw a diagram of the following form (this is a MWE):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

$$
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=-1cm]
&   A
\ar[ddd, controls={+(-7,0) and +(-7,0)},
start anchor=west,end anchor=west]
& B \\
& C
& D\\
E(BIG THING) & & \\
& F(BIG THING HERE, TOO) 
& 
\end{tikzcd}
$$

\end{document}
```

Sadly, this produces a diagram with strange spacing issues; the output looks like this (never mind the bad anchors of the arrow; I know how to fix that):

[image]

Note the large amount of white space on the left side of the diagram (the picture is left-aligned on Stack Exchange). Needless to say, this messes up the way my page looks (the actual diagram I want to draw now does not fit inside the margins because of the space on the left), so I'd like to understand tow things:

1. Why is this happening?
2. What can I do how to fix it?

Particular emphasis lies on the second point ;-)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43621/bounding-box-is-larger-than-expected-when-drawing-a-curved-path?rq=1, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290357/tikz-bounding-box-cropping-too-much-space-for-curves?rq=1.

Comment: @Cfr Thanks for your comment. However, the answers to the question the duplicate banner links to do not work in my case, since the actual diagram I'm interested in making can't be enclosed in a `tikzpicture` environment (tex capacity exceeded error), and hence solutions that only work in this environment are a no-go here. Do you think it would be a good idea to re-open the question, if I incorporate this information in it? Or am I overlooking something basic?

Comment: `tikzcd` creates a `tikzpicture` environment - you shouldn't need an additional one.

Comment: @cfr Thanks again for your reply. I'm now trying to play round with bounding boxes, but the command `\path[use as bounding box] (shape I want)` seems to only apply to certain parts of the diagram. I'm not sure if I should ask a new question, or not.

Comment: I'd ask a new question. This question is really a generic: how can I stop this happening? That's what the other question addresses. But now you know that stuff in theory but are having trouble applying it in this particular case, so either you could edit this one or ask a new one. But I don't think a new one would be unjustified and will probably be quicker, so I'd recommend that. You can include links to whatever questions if you think that's useful background (probably is).