# Control Points affect the size of Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, bezier

I have created the following graph using TikZ.

[image]

As you can see, the area of the `tikzpicture` is unnecessarily large. I believe that this is due to the inclusion of the invisible control points in the `tikzpicture`. Is there any way I can get TikZ to ignore them?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}

\begin{document}
    $\boxed{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Nodes
        \foreach \i in {1,...,3}{
            \node[circle, draw=black, thick, fill=gray!10] (\i) at (2.5*\i - 2.5, 2.5) {\i};
        }  

        \foreach \i in {4,...,6}{
            \node[circle, draw=black, thick, fill=gray!10] (\i) at (2.5*\i - 10,0) {\i};
           }   

        % Drawing
        \draw[thick] (1) -- (4);
        \draw[thick] (1) -- (5);
        \draw[thick] (1) -- (6);
        \draw[thick] (2) -- (6);
        \draw[thick] (3) -- (6);
        \draw[thick] (2) .. controls (-1, 5) and (-3, 1)  .. (4);
        \draw[thick] (2) .. controls (-3, 7) and (-5, -4) .. (5);
        \draw[thick] (3) .. controls (7, 1)  and (6, -3)  .. (5);
        \draw[thick, gray!50, dashed] (3) .. controls (10, 1)  and (6, -5)  .. (4);
        \draw[thick, gray!50, dashed] (3) .. controls (-4, 10)  and (-5, -5)  .. (4);
    \end{tikzpicture}}$
\end{document}
```

Also, on a side note, is there a way I can modify the `out` angle of the edges? I usually use the `to` command, e.g.

```
\draw (node1) to[out = 0] (node 2);
```

But I don't know how to do this for Bézier curves.

Comment: You can use `\clip (a,b) rectangle (c,d);` to clip.

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290357/121799). I think your question is a duplicate, but I do not want to use my dupehammer.

Comment: I do not think that you can add the `out` (nor `in`) to Bezier plots since this would overconstrain the system. (Bezier curves are solutions to quadratic or cubic equations, depending on the number of control points). However, you can play with the `looseness` parameter to adjust the shape of a path with fixed `in` and/or `out`. I personally find this more intuitive.

Comment: @marmot How would you do that?

Comment: `\draw (node1) to[out = 0,looseness=1.5] (node 2);`

Comment: @marmot I was not :) So I'll delete my comments.

Comment: Load the [`bbox` library](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-bbox) and use the `bezier bounding box` key on the last five paths.