# Tikz images are always shifted to the right and xshift, yshift and shift do not work

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello I have been making a drawing with Tikz and would like to set the position of this Tikz image on the beginning of the page but it seems the tikzpicture is stuck some 3 cm from the top of the page and about 4 cm to the right and the xshift and yshift commands are not working, although the rotate, xscale and yscale commands are working, also the curve i wish to shift is constructed with the "hobby" Tikz library.

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale =0.5,yscale=-1.1, xscale=1.2]

\draw [rotate=-12] (1.93,2.85) to [curve  through ={(4.09,2.77)..
(3.16,0.15)..(0.45,1.68)..(2.37,6.57)..(8.41,7.82)..(12.30,8.08)}]
(13.36,8.6) .. controls (14.45,8) and (15.50,7.8) .. (19.08,7.96) to
[curve  through ={(23.36,8.97)..(25.39,10.67)}] (25.22,12.77) 
.. controls (24.22,9.9) and (21.65,10.45)..(21.09,12.27) to [curve
through ={(23.46,15.72)..(27.28,12.86)..(25.40,8.13)..(21.72,6.40)..
(16.44,5.93)..(15.3,5.79)}] (14.49,5.31) .. controls (14.18,5.5) and 
(14,5.67)..(13.3,5.82) to [curve  through ={(12.4,5.92)..(8.55,5.89)..
(5.9,5.75)..(2.01,4.06)}] (1.93,2.85) ;


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to your code to see that the gaps are not as big as you may think. It is true, though, that the bounding box for these curves is not absolutely tight.

Comment: There is a feature request for tight bounding boxes for cubic Bézier curves https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/109/, but I don't think I'll implement it.  I don't really see the benefit from implementing something that complex to remedy one-off situations like this question.

Comment: The shift operators have no affect on the bounding box, which controls where a normal tikz (no overlay) is placed.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290357/121799) at length. I agree with Henri Menke that one does not have to rewrite Ti*k*Z to get a tight bounding box.  You could use the answers of this question to rectify the issue. One additional possible way out here is to base the bounding box on the points the curve runs through.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale =0.5,yscale=-1.1, xscale=1.2]
\begin{scope}[overlay]
\draw [rotate=-12,postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.005 with {\coordinate (x\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number});}}}] 
(1.93,2.85) to [curve  through ={(4.09,2.77)..
(3.16,0.15)..(0.45,1.68)..(2.37,6.57)..(8.41,7.82)..(12.30,8.08)}]
(13.36,8.6) .. controls (14.45,8) and (15.50,7.8) .. (19.08,7.96) to
[curve  through ={(23.36,8.97)..(25.39,10.67)}] (25.22,12.77) 
.. controls (24.22,9.9) and (21.65,10.45)..(21.09,12.27) to [curve
through ={(23.46,15.72)..(27.28,12.86)..(25.40,8.13)..(21.72,6.40)..
(16.44,5.93)..(15.3,5.79)}] (14.49,5.31) .. controls (14.18,5.5) and 
(14,5.67)..(13.3,5.82) to [curve  through ={(12.4,5.92)..(8.55,5.89)..
(5.9,5.75)..(2.01,4.06)}] (1.93,2.85) ;
\end{scope}
\path plot[variable=\i,samples at={1,...,200}] (x\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This leaves you with the problem that the figure is too wide to fit. Note also that `\noindent` had a bigger impact than the above trickery to reduce the space on the left. Of course, you could rescale it to fit.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "too wide to fit", it should be only a matter of displacing the image to the left in such a way as to center it in the page, i have been trying to do so with the clip command but it seems that it doesn't draw anything that is to the left of where text begins.

Comment: @FelipeDilho No. If you add stuff that is too wide to fit, it will overshoot on the right side of the page. You *could* wrap the `tikzpicture` into `\centerline{...}` but it is not good practice to have too wide stuff in the document.

Comment: To me it seems there is enough space to fit it in the page i just have to displace it some centimeters to the left.