# Tikz-cd: diagram does not look centered

Tags: tikz-cd

I have a `tikz-cd` diagram which does not want to sit in the middle of the page. I figured out it is because the names of the nodes are to long, because if I replace them all with `X`, then everything is fine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
Does not look centered...
\[
\begin{tikzcd} 
...\arrow[r]   & {H_{k+1}(\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R, H_-)} \arrow[r] & {H_{k+1}(\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R, H_+\cup H_-)}\ar[out=-20, in=160]{dll} \\
H_k(H_+\cup H_-, H_-) \arrow[r] &H_k(\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R, H_-)\arrow[r] &... \end{tikzcd}
\]

This looks much better:
\[
\begin{tikzcd} 
X\arrow[r]   & {X} \arrow[r] & {X}\ar[out=-20, in=160]{dll} \\
X \arrow[r] &X\arrow[r] &X \end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

View: https://www.overleaf.com/read/vyjykbkstykp

What can I do to shift my diagram into the middle of the page?

> (What I have tried: different environments and adding empty nodes on the right hand side).

Comment: In addition to the `overlay` option proposed by daleif, I suggest also you do `\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}` in the preamble and use `\RR` instead of `\mathbb R` (which, by the way, should be `\mathbb{R}`) and avoid useless braces around the diagram nodes. Also `...` should be `\dotsb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be due to the special arrow you use, try using this instead

```
\ar[out=-20, in=160,overlay]{dll}
```

I added the `overlay` option, then the size is ignored in the size calculations.

Comment: This probably uses a Bezier curve, and it is a known problem that the control points are taken into account in the bounding box calculation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290357/tikz-bounding-box-cropping-too-much-space-for-curves

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I did not realize that the curve was the problem, since it works fine with different nodes.