# Tikz in equation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following problem. I would like to use a tikz picture in an equation environment. The following is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Some text here.
\begin{equation*}
\left[
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick] (1, -1) .. controls (0.4, -1) and (0, -0.6) .. (0, 0);
  \draw[thick] (0, 0) .. controls (0, 0.6) and (0.6, 1) .. (1, 1);
  \draw[thick] (1, -0.5) .. controls (0.7, -0.5) and (0.5, -0.3) .. (0.5, 0);
  \draw[thick] (0.5, 0) .. controls (0.5, 0.3) and (0.7, 0.5) .. (1, 0.5);
  
  \draw[thick] (1, -1) .. controls (1.5, -1) and (1.75, -0.6) .. (1.75, -0.25);
  \draw[thick] (1, 0.5) .. controls (1.5, 0.5) and (1.75, 0.1) .. (1.75, -0.25);
  \draw[thick] (1, -0.5) .. controls (1.5, -0.5) and (1.75, -0.1) .. (1.75, 0.25);
  \draw[thick] (1, 1) .. controls (1.5, 1) and (1.75, 0.6) .. (1.75, 0.25);
  
  \draw[dashed] (1, -1.1) -- (1, 1.1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \right]
\end{equation*}
Some more text here
\end{document}
```

Now if I delete the "\left[ ... \right]", then it looks as expected:

[image]

But the result of the code above looks unexpected to me:

[image]

It looks as if the image would contain another white space under the actual graphic, which is not shown without the brackets. How can I get rid of this space?

Comment: Your image is all above the baseline. Try `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]`... (sorry, the previous comment was wrong in this case, but https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290357/tikz-bounding-box-cropping-too-much-space-for-curves still could be related for other figures)

Comment: Try [baseline=(current bounding box.center)].  You will still be off by {0.5\ht\strutbox-0.5\dp\strutbox} though.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. If you post this as an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Since you are loading `amsmath`, one solution is to use the environment `bmatrix` to obtain the left and right brackets.  You may leave then your TikZ code as it is.

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[thick] (1, -1) .. controls (0.4, -1) and (0, -0.6) .. (0, 0);
      \draw[thick] (0, 0) .. controls (0, 0.6) and (0.6, 1) .. (1, 1);
      \draw[thick] (1, -0.5) .. controls (0.7, -0.5) and (0.5, -0.3) .. (0.5, 0);
      \draw[thick] (0.5, 0) .. controls (0.5, 0.3) and (0.7, 0.5) .. (1, 0.5);
      
      \draw[thick] (1, -1) .. controls (1.5, -1) and (1.75, -0.6) .. (1.75, -0.25);
      \draw[thick] (1, 0.5) .. controls (1.5, 0.5) and (1.75, 0.1) .. (1.75, -0.25);
      \draw[thick] (1, -0.5) .. controls (1.5, -0.5) and (1.75, -0.1) .. (1.75, 0.25);
      \draw[thick] (1, 1) .. controls (1.5, 1) and (1.75, 0.6) .. (1.75, 0.25);
      
      \draw[dashed] (1, -1.1) -- (1, 1.1);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```