# How to reduce vertical space between text and a figure that contains tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, vertical-spacing, vertical

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every node/.style={circle,thin, fill=black}, % sets the properties for each ’state’ node
}

\begin{document}

Uma representação geométrica deste plano segue abaixo.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm,   
    every node/.style={
        circle, thin, inner sep = 2pt,fill, black!80
    },
    black!80
    ] 
    \node[label = {$1$}] (1) {};
    \node[right of=1,label = {$2$}] (2) {};
    \node[right of=2,label = {$3$}] (3) {};
    \node[below of=1,label = left:{$4$}] (4) {};
    \node[below of=2,label = {[label distance = .12cm]10:$5$}] (5) {};
    \node[below of=3,label = right:{$6$}] (6) {};
    \node[below of=4,label = below:{$7$}] (7) {};
    \node[below of=5,label = below:{$8$}] (8) {};
    \node[below of=6,label = below:{$9$}] (9) {};
    \draw[-]
    (1) edge[asparagus] (2)
    (2) edge[asparagus] (3)
    (4) edge[red!80] (5)
    (5) edge[red!80] (6)
    (7) edge[purple] (8)
    (8) edge[purple] (9)
    (3) edge[orange!80] (5)
    (5) edge[orange!80] (7)
    (1) edge[gray] (5)
    (5) edge[gray] (9)
    (3) edge[bleudefrance!80] (6)
    (6) edge[bleudefrance!80] (9)
    (1) edge[cyan!80] (4)
    (4) edge[cyan!80] (7)
    (2) edge[pink] (5)
    (5) edge[pink] (8)
    (2) edge[dashed] (4)
    (4) edge[dashed, out=225, in=225, looseness=2] (9)
    (1) edge[orange!80,dashed, out=200, in=225,looseness=2.5] (8)
    (8) edge[orange!80,dashed] (6)
    (3) edge[purple,dashed, out=140, in = 140, looseness =2] (4)
    (4) edge[purple,dashed] (8)
    (6) edge[cyan,dashed] (2)
    (2) edge[cyan,dashed, out=140, in=140, looseness = 2.5] (7); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me the following output:

[image]

As it's visible in the *output*, there is way too much vertical space between the space and the figure. This also happens if I try to write after the figure, i.e., there is also a big vertical space if I add text after the figure. Is there a way to decrease this spacing?

Comment: Everything in PGF/TikZ that's not a straight line is a Bézier curve. Calculating its bounding box isn't trivial so the authors of PGF chose to just add the control points (in addition to start and target) to the bounding box which at least covers the whole curve but oftentimes also more. Except for manually changing the bounding box, there are more automatic solutions in [Q43621](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43621) and [Q290357](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290357).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Qrrbrbirlbel . I am trying to adjust the boundig box manually but it's kinda hard, do you have any hint?

Comment: I was able to do it using Bezier bounding box option.

Comment: Yes, the [`bbox` library](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-bbox) is the result of one of [the answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501154) to the first linked question.

Comment: `below of` is deprecated (though has barely any effect here). Further reading: [Q9386](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386), [A94396](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94396).

Comment: Please add definition of used colors.

Comment: The definition of the used colors can be found here: http://latexcolor.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your MWE is not compilable. Missed are definition of edge colors.
- Try to use `bbox` library (available on CTAN):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, ]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}

\begin{document}

Uma representação geométrica deste plano segue abaixo.
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box,    % <----
node distance = 22mm,
  start chain = right,
   dot/.style = {circle, thin, inner sep = 2pt, fill=black!80},
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={dot}]
\node[label = {$1$}] (1) {};
    \node[right of=1,label = {$2$}] (2) {};
    \node[right of=2,label = {$3$}] (3) {};
    \node[below of=1,label = left:{$4$}] (4) {};
    \node[below of=2,label = {[label distance = .12cm]10:$5$}] (5) {};
    \node[below of=3,label = right:{$6$}] (6) {};
    \node[below of=4,label = below:{$7$}] (7) {};
    \node[below of=5,label = below:{$8$}] (8) {};
    \node[below of=6,label = below:{$9$}] (9) {};
        \end{scope}
\draw[-]
    (1) edge[asparagus] (2)      
    (2) edge[asparagus] (3)     
    (4) edge[red!80] (5)
    (5) edge[red!80] (6)
    (7) edge[purple] (8)
    (8) edge[purple] (9)
    (3) edge[orange!80] (5)
    (5) edge[orange!80] (7)
    (1) edge[gray] (5)
    (5) edge[gray] (9)
    (3) edge[bleudefrance!80] (6)
    (6) edge[bleudefrance!80] (9)
    (1) edge[cyan!80] (4)
    (4) edge[cyan!80] (7)
    (2) edge[pink] (5)
    (5) edge[pink] (8)
    (2) edge[dashed] (4)
    (4) edge[dashed, out=225, in=225, looseness=2] (9)
    (1) edge[orange!80,dashed, out=200, in=225,looseness=2.5] (8)
    (8) edge[orange!80,dashed] (6)
    (3) edge[purple,dashed, out=140, in = 140, looseness =2] (4)
    (4) edge[purple,dashed] (8)
    (6) edge[cyan,dashed] (2)
    (2) edge[cyan,dashed, out=140, in=140, looseness = 2.5] (7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

After forcing of compilation I get the following result:

[image]

**Addendum:**
Off-topic: an example of redesign of the OP image  (as style as well of code). Changed are:

- Positions of labels are defined labels anchors, which are the same for all nodes.
- Lines between nodes are drawn in background.
- Colors of lines are selected from default `xcolor` colors (it is loaded by `tikz` package). Now MWE can be compiled without warnings and errors.
- Nodes are placed by use of `chains` library. This make code shorter and more clear.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, ]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,
            showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, 
                bbox,                        % <----
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

Uma representação geométrica deste plano segue abaixo.
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box,    % <----
node distance = 22mm,
  start chain = right,
   dot/.style = {circle, thin, inner sep = 2pt, fill=black!80,
                 on chain,
                 label=#1, node contents={},
                 },
every label/.append style = {font=\small, fill=white, anchor=south west,
                             inner sep=1.2pt, outer sep=1pt}
                    ]
\node (1) [dot = $1$];
\node (2) [dot = $2$];
\node (3) [dot = $3$];
    
\node (4) [dot = $4$, below=of 1];
\node (5) [dot = $5$];
\node (6) [dot = $6$];
    
\node (7) [dot = $7$, below=of 4];
\node (8) [dot = $8$];
\node (9) [dot = $9$];

\scoped[on background layer]
\draw   (1) edge[olive]     (2) edge[olive]     (3)     %   asparagus
        (4) edge[red!80]    (5) edge[red!80]    (6)
        (7) edge[purple]    (8) edge[purple]    (9)
    %
        (3) edge[orange!80] (5) edge[orange!80] (7)
        (1) edge[gray]      (5) edge[gray]      (9)
    %
        (1) edge[cyan!80]   (4) edge[cyan!80]   (7)
        (2) edge[pink]      (5) edge[pink]      (8)
        (3) edge[blue!80]   (6) edge[blue!80]   (9)   %   bleudefrance!80
        ;
\draw[orange!80,dashed] 
        (6) to  (8) edge[out=225, in=220,looseness=2.5] (1);
\draw[dashed]       
        (2) to  (4) edge[out=225, in=225, looseness=2]  (9);
\draw[cyan,dashed]  
        (6) to  (2) edge[out=140, in=140, looseness=2.5]    (7);
\draw[purple!80,dashed] 
        (8) to  (4) edge[out=140, in=140, looseness=2]      (3);

\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `float` package, like in this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,calc,lipsum,float}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
            \draw[gray!30] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
            \draw[-latex,blue] (-3.4,0)--(3.4,0) node[right] (x) {\footnotesize $x$};
            \draw[-latex,blue] (0,-3.4)--(0,3.4) node[above] (y) {\footnotesize $y$};
            \foreach \i in {-3,-2,...,3}{
                \foreach \j in {-3,-2,...,3}{
                    %\pgfmathsetmacro\h{int(\i+\j)};
                    \filldraw[black] (\i,\j) circle(.8pt);
                    \node[blue,right] at (\i,\j+.1) (\i) {\tiny (\i,\j)};
                    
                }
            } 
        \end{tikzpicture}  
    \caption{Tikzpcture below text}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[2]   
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]