# Tikzpicture path creating a lot of whitespace

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic, white-space

This code

```
\documentclas{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{
    \fbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[main/.style = {draw, circle}] 
        
        \node[main] (1) {$1$};
        \node[main] (2) [above of=1] {$2$};
        \node[main] (3) [right of=1] {$3$};
        \node[main] (4) [right of=2] {$4$};
        \node[main] (5) [right of=3] {$5$};
        \node[main] (6) [right of=4] {$6$};
        
        \draw[->] (1) edge node[midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 1} (2);
        \draw[->] (2) edge node[midway, below, sloped] {\tiny 1-$\epsilon$} (3);
        \draw[->] (2) edge node[midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 1} (4);
        \draw[->] (3) edge node[midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 1} (4);
        \draw[->] (4) edge node[midway, below, sloped] {\tiny 1-$\epsilon$} (5);
        \draw[->] (4) edge node[midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 1} (6);
        \draw[<->] (6) edge node[midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 1} (5);
        \draw[->] (5) edge node[midway, below, sloped] {\tiny 1} (3);
        \draw[->] (3) edge node[midway, below, sloped] {\tiny 1}(1);
        \path[->] (6)  edge[bend left=90, out=150, looseness = 2] node[midway, below, sloped] {\tiny 100} (1);
    \end{tikzpicture} }
    }
\caption{An example of nearest neighbor working poorly}
\label{tikz:NN_bad_sol}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Yields this output

[image: Output]

From what I could figure out, the problem is being caused by the last path. If I remove it, the picture is centered and has no whitespace. I don't understand how edge 6 -> 1 is creating so much whitespace

Comment: What creates this empty space is the bent curve, because it uses control points that are far away from the curve, hence the space. You should clip your picture to avoid that. On a side note, there's no `\begin{document}` in your code.

Comment: Thank you, @SebGlav, I wasn't aware of control points, your suggestion works perfectly. As for the side note, you are right, the MWE wasn't working very well :)

Comment: Just add `\clip (-1,-1) rectangle (3.5,1.8);` on the beginning of your `tikzpicture`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665769/how-to-reduce-vertical-space-between-text-and-a-figure-that-contains-tikzpicture/665770#665770  . Package `bbox`  contain good explanation about problem you discussed in question