# The inserted picture does not start from the left edge of the paper. How to fix it?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I drew a glucose molecule (in its chair conformation) with the package tikz. And then I took a screenshot and edited it. After this I inserted this picture into my LaTeX document. The problem is the following: I would like the picture to start from the very left edge of the paper but unfortunatelly, it is not that easy for me because there is always a white space (about 1-2 cm). How to change this space to 0 cm?

A picture of my problem:

[image: Part of glucose]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,chemfig,mathtools,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,fullpage,graphicx,xcolor,cancel}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\definecolor{zold}{HTML}{99FF99}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{5cm}
\begin{center}
\textsc{\Huge Title}\\
\vspace*{1cm}
\textsc{\Large Author}\\
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=18cm]{nagyglcc2.png}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: My crystal ball is showing nothing but dense haze at the moment. :-( It would be truly helpful if you showed the code that gives rise to the issue you're looking to fix.

Comment: If adding `\noindent` immediately before the `tixzpicture` does not resolve the issue then, the problem is in how you are drawing the picture. You can try adding a bounding box to see the actual edges of the picture. For example, see [Bounding box is larger than expected when drawing a curved path](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43624/4301). Otherwise, please post the a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Is the white space to the left by any chance of the same size than the margin?

Comment: Why are you making a screenshot when you have tikz code? It won't improve the quality.

Comment: I was probably thinking of the same thing as @samcarter: if you replace `\includegraphics[...]{...}` with `\hspace*{-\dimexpr \oddsidemargin + 1in} \includegraphics[...]{...}`, do you get what you want?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Is above picture what you looking for? I move it to left paper border with help of `changepage` package. In MWE I deleted all packages from your MWE, which not contributed to solution and add `showframe` to see page layout, which I determine by `geometry package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{showframe}% for showing page layout
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{5cm}
    \begin{center}
\textsc{\Huge Title}\\
\vspace*{1cm}
\textsc{\Large Author}\\
    \end{center}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{-\oddsidemargin-1in}{}
    \includegraphics[width=18cm,height=2cm]{example-image}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Note: float (`figure`) cannot be used inside `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`. This part of your code I don't understand (if probably you like to add caption to figure, let me know).

Comment: +1!  But may I suggest that you make the first argument of the `adjustwidth*` environment dinamically conform to the actual margin in force?

Comment: Indeed, I’ve tried it and `\begin{adjustwidth}{-\dimexpr \oddsidemargin + 1in}{}` seems to work fine! (:-)