# How to make such a table that fits to the page limits?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable, colortbl, rowcolor

I guess this is somewhat easy but I'm struggling with it for a while right now. How can I make such a table that fits perfectly to the given page layout and has (automatic) line breaks and the first row colored in black? And is it possible that (the last parts of) this table can be broken to the next page too if it does not fully fit at the end of the previous page?

[image]

Thank you so much.

Comment: you might want to have a look at the tabularx package

Comment: `tabulary` is less know, but also handy!

Comment: Please add to your question a minimal document, which will show your attempt so far. Do you really mean that table should be extended to page border and not of text ones?

Comment: Have you tried with longtable instead of tabularx to break the table to the net page?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Answer (score 2):

For example with `tabularx`:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
   \caption{My table}
   \label{my table}
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{22mm}>{\raggedright}X>{\raggedright}Xp{33mm}}
     \rowcolor{black}
     \textcolor{white}{Column 1}
       & \texcolor{white}{Column 2}
           & \textcolor{white}{Column 3}
               & \textcolor{white}{Column 4}   \\
     A & B & C & D                             \\
   \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

For more, please provide minimal but complete document (starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`), which will show your attempts so far. Based on it, I can (easily) complete my code to a MWE (just now I haven't to make MWE from scratch).

**Edit:**
If your really like to star table at page border, than you question is duplicate to  question [the-inserted-picture-does-not-start-from-the-left-edge-of-the-paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335571/the-inserted-picture-does-not-start-from-the-left-edge-of-the-paper-how-to-fix). See, if answer there gives what  you like to obtain. In your case you than only need to adopt `tabularx` width to page width.

Answer (score 1):

For a table  which 
1) fits the text width; 2) can break  across pages, you can use the `ltablex` package, which brings  the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`.  Add the directive `\keepXColumns` so  that `X` columns will have their calculated width. Otherwise, they will have their natural width up to the calculated width.