# Huge gap after tikzpicture in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

The following is a MWE

`\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.695cm,y=0.685cm]
    \clip(-1.72,-5.46) rectangle (21.28,5.38);
    \draw  (3.54,1.5) ellipse (2.02cm and 2cm);
    \draw  (8.24,1.82) ellipse (2.11cm and 2.08cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   $B_\alpha$ 
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

On compiling the above tex, we see that there is a huge gap between the tikzpicture and the text. How to reduce this gap?
[image]
I am not so familiar with tikzpicture. Any help and suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you need that `\clip`? That seems to cause the huge gap.

Comment: The y-coordinate of your clip is too small. If you use `\draw` instead of `\clip` you can see the clip. Tune it and then turn it into `\clip` again. Of course you can just leave out the clip and center the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: You don't need `\clip`. Once a `tikzpicture` is finished, its bounding box is adjusted to fit all used coordinates, visible or not. [Sometimes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43621/bounding-box-is-larger-than-expected-when-drawing-a-curved-path) we need to adjust the bounding box, but not in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put the comments above into an answer the code would look like this.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.695cm,y=0.685cm]
%    \clip(-1.72,-5.46) rectangle (21.28,5.38);
    \draw  (3.54,1.5) ellipse (2.02cm and 2cm);
    \draw  (8.24,1.82) ellipse (2.11cm and 2.08cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   $B_\alpha$
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

*If* you try to center the picture horizontally (just an idea of mine) with the clipping it would be better to use something like this:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.695cm,y=0.685cm]
%    \clip(-1.72,-5.46) rectangle (21.28,5.38);
    \draw  (3.54,1.5) ellipse (2.02cm and 2cm);
    \draw  (8.24,1.82) ellipse (2.11cm and 2.08cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

    \begin{itemize}
\item   $B_\alpha$
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```