# how to get rid of the strange spacing to the right of a tikzpicture inside a tcolorbox?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

For a LaTeX/beamer presentation i want to add those nice lifted drop shadows which `tcolorbox` provides to all of my images. This worked fine so far for images included via `includegraphics` but not so fine for images drawn with tikzs (included via `tikzpicture`). The problem is, there is a spacing inside the tcolorbox between the `tikzpicture` and the right frame of the `tcolorbox`.
Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,drop large lifted shadow,boxsep=0mm,left=0mm%
              right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=0.5pt]%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0.0, 0.0) grid (5.0, 5.0);
  \draw [brown] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{document}
```

This space can get drastically reduced by adding the hbox option as I recently found out:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,drop large lifted shadow,boxsep=0mm,left=0mm,hbox,% <---- added the hox option here!
              right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=0.5pt]%
```

but there is still some spacing! How get I get rid of the rest?

edit: i have just noticed that tcolorbox is not the problem! The unwanted space to the right is created by Tikz. I tested this by putting the tikzpicture part only into a standalone environment and created a pdf from that (with pdflatex). The resulting pdf already had the unwanted space.

Maybe there are other reasons but tcolorbox can be ruled out though.
A workaround for me at the moment is to create standalone pdfs from all of my tikzpictures (which are a lot) and then apply pdfcrop to all of them.
The cropped images can be used fine within a tcolorbox then.

Comment: `tcolorbox` is actually a `tikzpicture`, you're nesting `ticzpicture` environments, which is not recommended, also there is a `,` missing in your `tcolorbox` options list

Comment: I see no spacing with a current tcolorbox (and the hbox-option).

Comment: `hbox` works for me

Comment: I do not know what to say, if i compile the example with hbox i get this result: http://imgur.com/a/ONI1o there is a cleary visible space to the right.

Comment: @Oliver: What is the version of the `tcolorbox`  package installed on your system? The newest is `4.02`, released about one month ago

Comment: I am not sure, i use the version provided by the package management system of openSUSE tumbleweed, the package is part of Texlive. The version it provides is: 2016.113.3.91svn40792-30.2 it was last updated/patched december the 7th in 2016.

Comment: this unwanted space that you mention appears in `TikZ` pictures where control points are needed. In this case, the boundinx box is wrong, because it includes all these `phantom` points and `tcolorbox` or `standalone` cannot crop them because they are based in tikz boundingbox. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43621/bounding-box-is-larger-than-expected-when-drawing-a-curved-path?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Are you sure? Because none of the other persons answering here have problems with the bounding box in my example. I also tried manual setting the bounding box and/or adding a clip as mentioned in the link you posted, but the result was the same. So i the bounding box probably is not the issue here i guess.

Answer (score 1):

This document (with the hbox) option

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,drop large lifted shadow,boxsep=0mm,left=0mm,hbox,%
              right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=0.5pt]%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0.0, 0.0) grid (5.0, 5.0);
  \draw [brown] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

gives this output with a current texlive 2016:

[image]

and this with texlive 2015

[image]

So there was a bug leading to bad spacing but it has been resolved, so you should update your system.