# Narrower kerning of symbols generated by Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, kerning

I'm using LaTeX to render a set of custom glyphs. Each glyph is perfectly rectangular, at a 3.5 x 5 aspect ratio, and they're defined something like this (the following example just lines the borders of the glyph):

```
\newcommand\glyph[1][1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
    \draw[lightgray] (0,0) to (0,4);
    \draw[lightgray] (0,0) to (3,0);
    \draw[lightgray] (3,0) to (3,4);
    \draw[lightgray] (0,4) to (3,4);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Each glyph is rendering correctly. When I invoke them in text:

```
\begin{document}
\glyph\glyph\glyph\glyph
\end{document}
```

I get some decently-kerned glyphs:

[image]

However, this isn't enough. I'd like to get the gap between characters down to a couple of pixels, if possible. How would I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your macros are suffering from the "missing `%` syndrome" :) Add a `%` here: `\newcommand\glyph[1][1]{% <--` and here: `\end{tikzpicture}% <--`.

Comment: That was the solution, thank you

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Well, it was a partial solution. While it did fix the wide kerning issue I was having, I'd like the kerning to go even narrower, if possible. I've edited my question to make that clear now

Comment: For future reference, I found the solution to the second problem too, in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43621/bounding-box-is-larger-than-expected-when-drawing-a-curved-path)

Comment: For future reference, provide a complete working example, not just code snippets.  When I put your snippets into a code framework, I do not get the separated images you show, but totally adjacent images.  I would vote to close this as a duplicate, but I am unable, having recently voted to reopen it prior to your recent comment on "issue 2"

Comment: And you can shorten your code with `\draw[lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);` instead of your `\draws`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I've done it for you :)