# Tikz-Network angle creates extra margin

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the package tikz-network (https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-network?lang=en).

Following is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    %\SetVertexStyle[fontsize=\large]
    \Vertices[IdAsLabel,size=0.5,color=white]{data/vertices4x4.csv}
    \Edges[]{data/edges1_4x4.csv}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Where data/vertices4x4.csv is

```
id, x, y
0;0, 0, 0
0;1, 0, -2
0;2, 0, -4
0;3, 0, -6
1;0, 2, 0
1;1, 2, -2
1;2, 2, -4
1;3, 2, -6
2;0, 4, 0
2;1, 4, -2
2;2, 4, -4
2;3, 4, -6
3;0, 6, 0
3;1, 6, -2
3;2, 6, -4
3;3, 6, -6
```

and data/edges1_4x4.csv is

```
u, v, bend, style
0;0, 1;0, 0, dashed
0;1, 1;1, 0, dashed
0;2, 1;2, 0, dashed
0;3, 1;3, 0, dashed
1;0, 2;0, 0, dashed
1;1, 2;1, 0, dashed
1;2, 2;2, 0, dashed
1;3, 2;3, 0, dashed
2;0, 3;0, 0, dashed
2;1, 3;1, 0, dashed
2;2, 3;2, 0, dashed
2;3, 3;3, 0, dashed
3;0, 0;0, 190, dashed
3;1, 0;1, 190, dashed
3;2, 0;2, 190, dashed
3;3, 0;3, 190, dashed
```

If I keep the angle 190 in edges1_4x4.csv, I get an extra (approx. 5cm) margin in my tikz picture. While, if I keep this angle to be 50, there is no such margin. Can you please tell me a way to remove the extra margin in case of angle 190?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome. I can't reproduce 5cm extra, but it is known that [the bounding box for Bezier curves is to generous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43621). One ad hoc fix is to adjust it by hand. This can be done with the command

```
\path[use as bounding box] (-1,-7) rectangle (7,0.8);
```

where the coordinates of the rectangle are adjusted by hand in this case. A less cumbersome solution is to exclude the edges from the bounding box. This can be achieved by putting the command in an `overlay` scope,

```
\begin{scope}[overlay]
\Edges[]{edges1_4x4.csv}
\end{scope}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{vertices4x4.csv}
id, x, y
0;0, 0, 0
0;1, 0, -2
0;2, 0, -4
0;3, 0, -6
1;0, 2, 0
1;1, 2, -2
1;2, 2, -4
1;3, 2, -6
2;0, 4, 0
2;1, 4, -2
2;2, 4, -4
2;3, 4, -6
3;0, 6, 0
3;1, 6, -2
3;2, 6, -4
3;3, 6, -6
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{edges1_4x4.csv}
u, v, bend, style
0;0, 1;0, 0, dashed
0;1, 1;1, 0, dashed
0;2, 1;2, 0, dashed
0;3, 1;3, 0, dashed
1;0, 2;0, 0, dashed
1;1, 2;1, 0, dashed
1;2, 2;2, 0, dashed
1;3, 2;3, 0, dashed
2;0, 3;0, 0, dashed
2;1, 3;1, 0, dashed
2;2, 3;2, 0, dashed
2;3, 3;3, 0, dashed
3;0, 0;0, 190, dashed
3;1, 0;1, 190, dashed
3;2, 0;2, 190, dashed
3;3, 0;3, 190, dashed
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    %\SetVertexStyle[fontsize=\large]
    \Vertices[IdAsLabel,size=0.5,color=white]{vertices4x4.csv}
    \Edges[]{edges1_4x4.csv}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Original bounding box.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \path[use as bounding box] (-1,-7) rectangle (7,0.8);
    %\SetVertexStyle[fontsize=\large]
    \Vertices[IdAsLabel,size=0.5,color=white]{vertices4x4.csv}
    \Edges[]{edges1_4x4.csv}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Modified bounding box.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    %\SetVertexStyle[fontsize=\large]
    \Vertices[IdAsLabel,size=0.5,color=white]{vertices4x4.csv}
    \begin{scope}[overlay]
    \Edges[]{edges1_4x4.csv}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Edges overlay.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\fbox`es are only to guide the eye.