# When should we use \rput, \nput, and \uput?

Tags: pstricks

I am writing a short tutorial for my friends about PSTricks. So I have to systematically explain the available macros such as `\nput`, `\rput` and `\uput` (among others) and reduce the possibility of confusion that might happen to my friends.

I am also confused with the naming convention adopted by PSTricks  for the macros above. What do `n`, `u`, `r` actually stand for? And what did the author want them to behave specially?

If one macro can be replaced by other macros without much effort, I will suggest the reader to forget it and use the more powerful ones. Remembering many macros (with slightly different feature but replaceable) seem to be difficult for the beginners.

Comment: The basic command is `\rput`, the others are convenience commands building on `\rput` for special situations.

Comment: no, `\rput` is _not_ the basic command.

Comment: the _basic_  command is the internal `\psput@`, which is used by all others. And _ variant_ means only the use but _not_ the command itself. And there are a lot of other put commands.

Comment: @Herbert My comment was based on the description of `\rput` in the pstricks documentation, where it is described as the most basic command.  `\psput@` is not a user level command, however you are correct that the other comands build on `\psput@` rather than `\rput`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\nput` node put

`\rput` ref put

`\uput` user put

`\aput` above node put

`\cput` center node put

`\bput` below node put

Comment: `\uput`'s name is a bit funny. :-)

Comment: Which one is regarded as the obsolete one?

Comment: no one of the above!