# How do we explain the behavior of \rput, \psGetNodeCenter and saveNodeCoors?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

### Introduction

I am writing a tutorial on a short introduction to PSTricks for newbies. I got obstacles to explain how  a node `A` (for example), `\rput`, `(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)` and `(!N-A.x N-A.y)` work by design.

I have read the `pst-node` documentation as shown below.

[image]

[image]

And the following is taken from page 35-36:

[image]

The manual says:

- The transformation matrix will be reset by `\psGetNodeCenter`.
- `(!N-A.x N-A.y)` is not affected by `\rput`.

Even though I read it many times, I still get confused. The statements are too short.

### Problem

Please consider the following figure for the remaining discussion.

[image]

- Case 1

  A node `A` is defined outside `\rput` and a dot is translated by `\rput`.

  - with `(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)`

    ```
    \pnode(2,2){A}
    \rput(1,1){\psdots(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)}
    ```
  - with `(!N-A.x N-A.y)`

    ```
    \pnode(2,2){A}
    \rput(1,1){\psdots(!N-A.x N-A.y)}
    ```

  The results are different. `\rput` only affects `(!N-A.x N-A.y)`.
- Case 2

  A node `A` is defined inside `\rput` and a dot is translated by `\rput`.

  - with `(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)`

    ```
    \rput(1,1){\pnode(2,2){A}\psdots(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)}
    ```
  - with `(!N-A.x N-A.y)`

    ```
    \rput(1,1){\pnode(2,2){A}\psdots(!N-A.x N-A.y)}
    ```

  The results are identical. `\rput` affects both.
- Case 3

  A node `A` is defined inside `\rput` and a dot is defined outside `\rput`.

  - with `(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)`

    ```
     \rput(1,1){\pnode(2,2){A}}
     \psdots(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)
    ```
  - with `(!N-A.x N-A.y)`

    ```
     \rput(1,1){\pnode(2,2){A}}
     \psdots(!N-A.x N-A.y)
    ```

  The results are different. `\rput` only affects `(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)`.

The MWE is given as follows.

```
\documentclass[margin=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=5pt}
\psset{saveNodeCoors,linecolor=red}
\everypsbox{\color{blue}}
\begin{document}

\begin{psmatrix}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](3,3)
    \rput(1,1){Case 1-A}
    \pnode(2,2){A}
    \rput(1,1){\psdots(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)}
\end{pspicture}
&
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](3,3)
    \rput(1,1){Case 1-B}
    \pnode(2,2){A}
    \rput(1,1){\psdots(!N-A.x N-A.y)}
\end{pspicture}
\\
% case 2
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](3,3)
    \rput(1,1){Case 2-A}
    \rput(1,1){\pnode(2,2){A}\psdots(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)}
\end{pspicture}
&
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](3,3)
    \rput(1,1){Case 2-B}
    \rput(1,1){\pnode(2,2){A}\psdots(!N-A.x N-A.y)}
\end{pspicture}
\\
% case 3
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](3,3)
    \rput(1,1){Case 3-A}
    \rput(1,1){\pnode(2,2){A}}
    \psdots(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)
\end{pspicture}
&
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](3,3)
    \rput(1,1){Case 3-B}
    \rput(1,1){\pnode(2,2){A}}
    \psdots(!N-A.x N-A.y)
\end{pspicture}
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

### Question

How do I have to explain their behaviors to the newbies as the statements in the documentation seem to be unclear?

Note: As `(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)` is identical to `(A)`, `(A)` will not be discussed here.

> If you are a teacher, how do you explain it to your
>   students?

Comment: although i cannot comment on pstricks being a newbie to pstricks. I am very happy to hear that your are writing `short intro to pstricks`. It would be very interesting. all the best.

Comment: @Herbert, where are you? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial point is understanding the difference between a node `(A)`, which is created by `\pnode`, and a pair of coordinates `(x,y)`:

- A coordinate pair, e.g. `(1,1)` specifies a *relative* point. Its position depends on the current environment, whether its `surrounded by \psdot(1,1) text`, or shifted with `\rput(2,2){\psdot(1,1)}` etc.
- A node `(A)` refers to an absolute, fixed point on the page. This is independent of the environment.

The following example resumes this.

```
\documentclass[pstricks, margin=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2,2)
    \rput(1,1){%
        \pnode(1,1){A}}
    \psdot(A)
    \pnode(1,1){B}
    \rput(1,1){%
        \psdot[linecolor=red](B)}
    \end{pspicture}
  \end{document}
```

The black dot is placed at `(2,2`), because `\rput` shifts the coordinate pair `(1,1`), which is used to define node `A`. The red dots remains at `(1,1)` because `\rput` has no effect on `(B)` after its definition:

[image]

That's the essence of all node-stuff.

Concerning `\psGetNodeCenter`, you are right: in this respect using `(!\psGetNodeCenter{A} A.x A.y)` is equivalent to `(A)`.

The parameter `saveNodeCoors` saves the *relative* coordinates at the time of the node definition. I.e. adding dots at `(!N-A.x N-A.y)` and `(!N-B.x N-B.y)` in the above example places two dots at `(1,1)`, which are the coordinate pairs used to define both nodes `A` and `B`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, margin=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid, saveNodeCoors](2,2)
    \rput(1,1){%
        \pnode(1,1){A}}
    \psdot(A)
    \pnode(1,1){B}
    \rput(1,1){%
        \psdot[linecolor=red](B)}
    %
    \psdot[dotstyle=+, dotscale=2](!N-A.x N-A.y)
    \psdot[dotstyle=x, dotscale=2](!N-B.x N-B.y)
    \end{pspicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Resuming this:

- Coordinate pairs like `(1, 1)` or node expressions with `! N-A.x N-A.y` are relative and are subject to scaling and translation like with `\rput`, `\scale`, `\translate` and such.
- Nodes `(A)` and node expressions with `\psGetNodeCenter` are fixed, "immutable" points.