# Why can't the abscissa and ordinate obtained from \psGetNodeCenter be reflected?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node, pst-eucl

Consider the following simplified code.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}

%\def\xy#1{!\psGetNodeCenter{#1} #1.x #1.y}% cannot  be reflected!
\def\xy#1{!N-#1.x N-#1.y}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-1)(3,3)
    \pstGeonode
        (2,0){A}
        (2,2){B}
    \nodexn{.25(A)+.25(B)+(0,2.5)}{C'}
    \pstGeonode(C'){C}
    \def\common{\psline(\xy{A})(\xy{B})(\xy{C})}%
    \pscustom
    {
        \common
        \reversepath
        \scale{-1 1}
        \common
        \closepath
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why can't the abscissa and ordinate obtained from `\psGetNodeCenter` be reflected?

Comment: You'd have to redefine the (same) nodes after setting `\scale{-1 1}` or `\psset{xunit=-1}`, I think.

Comment: I curious about what happened to your other question related to these points.  I've been playing around with it and found it rather perplexing.  Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: I got very different results just by changing the border....  So it sems there is still a question:  "Why must you go through code as you do below?"  It seems something isn't working correctly with `\nodexn`.

Comment: I think you should repost it as a question about `\nodexn` or report it as a bug.

Comment: I was trying to get it work outside of `\pscustom` and I was still getting strange values.  I boiled my examples down to just loading `pstricks` and `pst-node`.  I did not load `pst-eucl`.  Performance differed if I used `article` document class.  If I used `standalone` I got different results depending on how `border` was set in the class options.

Comment: This is the same behavior as explained in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163411/33933 : I would consider closing this question as duplicate because it is about the difference between `saveNodeCoors` and `\psGetNodeCenter`.