# Why do we need to buffer the pst-eucl nodes before passing them to \rput?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node, pst-eucl

Behavior of nodes defined `pst-eucl` seems to be different from those defined in `pst-plot`.

In the section titled `Direct node`, I attempted to create a square with `pq` as it base inclined at a slope of line `pq`. Unfortunately, it produces a wrong output.

But if I buffered the rotated point with a node defined in `pst-node`, I got the correct output.

This inconsistent behavior might cause confusion and difficult to debug. What do you think?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}

\section*{Direct node}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,saveNodeCoors,NodeCoorPrefix=N](10,10)
    \pstGeonode(4,8){p}(4,6){r}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=90]{p}{r}[q]
    \rput{!Nqy Nry sub Nqx Nrx sub atan}(r){\psframe(!Nqx Nqy Nrx Nry Pyth2 dup)}
\end{pspicture}

\vspace{4cm}
\section*{Indirect node}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,saveNodeCoors,NodeCoorPrefix=N](10,10)
    \pstGeonode(4,8){p}(4,6){r}
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=90]{p}{r}[temp]
    \pnodes(temp){q}
    \rput{!Nqy Nry sub Nqx Nrx sub atan}(r){\psframe(!Nqx Nqy Nrx Nry Pyth2 dup)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Question

Why do we need to buffer the `pst-eucl` nodes before passing them to `\rput`? Why don't make the behavior of nodes defined in `pst-eucl` consistent with those defined in `pst-plot`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code without an intermediate node doesn't work, because `\pstRotation` internally uses `\rput`.

When a node is shifted with `\rput`, the coordinates saved with `saveNodeCoors` cannot be used together with other coordinates of nodes defined outside of the `\rput` (see [How do we explain the behavior of \rput, \psGetNodeCenter and saveNodeCoors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163411/33933) for a more detailled explanation).