# Errors due to operation on N-P.y and N-P.x of nodes produced by \pstTranslation

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

In the following MWE, only the combination of `\pstTranslation` and angle calculated via `N-P.y N-P.x atan 90 sub` produces error.

How to solve it?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{saveNodeCoors,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}

\def\Pic#1#2#3{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,5)
% node type switch
\ifnum#1=0\relax
    \pnode(0,0){O}
    \pnode(2,1){A}
    \pnode(1,4){B}
\else
    \pstGeonode
        (0,0){O}
        (2,1){A}
        (1,4){B}
\fi
% transformation switch
\ifnum#2=0\relax
    \nodexn{(B)-(A)}{P}
\else   
    \pstTranslation{A}{B}{O}[P]
\fi
%
    \pcline(A)(B)
    \pscircle(A){1}
% angle calculation switch
\ifnum#3=0\relax
    \uput{1}[(P)]{!\psGetNodeCenter{P}P.y P.x atan 90 sub}(>A){\psline[linecolor=red]{->}(0,1)}
\else
    \uput{1}[(P)]{!N-P.y N-P.x atan 90 sub}(>A){\psline[linecolor=red]{->}(0,1)}
\fi
\end{pspicture}}


\begin{document}
\Pic{1}{0}{1}
\Pic{1}{0}{0}
%\Pic{1}{1}{1}
\Pic{1}{1}{0}
\Pic{0}{0}{1}
\Pic{0}{0}{0}
%\Pic{0}{1}{1}
\Pic{0}{1}{0}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{!\psGetNodeCenter{P}P.y P.x atan 90 sub ...`  can only be used with default PSTricks nodes but not with one defined by `\pstGeonode`. Use something like

```
[...]
\pnode(P){P1}
\uput{1}[(P)]{!\psGetNodeCenter{P1} P1.y P1.x atan 90 sub}(>A){%
  \psline[linecolor=red]{->}(0,1)}
[...]
```

Comment: But my question has _no_ problem with `\psGetNodeCenter{P}P.y P.x atan 90 sub`.

Comment: You use `\uput{1}[(P)]{!N-P.y N-P.x...` P ist defined by `\pstGeonode`. All nodes defined by `pst-eucl` are special and not saved by `saveNodeCoors`. See edited answer for a fix

Comment: I think your last comment is not 100% correct. This issue is not specific to `\pstGeonode` but it is about a node created inside `\rput`. For more details, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Christoph's explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163411/87876), I can summarize as follows:

> If `B` is a node created by a node creating macro (either `\pnode` or `\pstGeonode`) inside a transforming macro (`\rput`, `\uput` or others) then the point `(!N-B.y N-B.x)` provided by `saveNodeCoors=true` will *not* be the same as `(!\psGetNodeCenter{B} B.y B.x)` or `(B)`. Buffering `B` via either `\pnode(B){C}` or `\pstGeonode(B){C}` is a way to make them behave the same.

In the following examples,

- the red dots represents dots created with `(!N-B.x N-B.y)`.
- the green dots represents dots created with `(!N-C.x N-C.y)`.
- the blue dots represents dots created with `(B)` or `(!\psGetNodeCenter{B} B.y B.x)`. As `(B)` behaves the same as  `(!\psGetNodeCenter{B} B.y B.x)`, only the usage of `(B)` is given.

The green `(!N-C.x N-C.y)` and blue `(B)` dots are placed at the same location but not for the red `(!N-B.x N-B.y)` dots.

### Case 1: Node creation with literal `(x,y)`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors,showgrid](4,6)
    \rput(1,2){\pnode(3,4){B}}
    \pnode(B){C}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red](!N-B.x N-B.y){4pt}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=green](!N-C.x N-C.y){3pt}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=blue](B){2pt}
\end{pspicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remarks:

```
\rput(1,2){\pnode(3,4){B}}
\pnode(B){C}
```

produces the following result.

- `(B)=(1+3,2+4)` <--- Effect of translation
- `N-B.y=4` and `N-B.x=3` <--- No effect of translation
- `(C)=(B)=(1+3,2+4)`

### Case 2: Node creation with another node

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors,showgrid](4,6)
    \pnode(3,4){A}
    \rput(1,2){\pnode(A){B}}
    \pnode(B){C}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red](!N-B.x N-B.y){4pt}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=green](!N-C.x N-C.y){3pt}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=blue](B){2pt}
\end{pspicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remarks:

```
\pnode(3,4){A}
\rput(1,2){\pnode(A){B}}
\pnode(B){C}
```

produces the following result.

- `(B)=(A)=(3,4)` <--- No effect of translation
- `N-B.y=4-2` and `N-B.x=3-1` <--- Effect of translation, but it is reversed. Is it strange?
- `(C)=(B)=(3,4)`

### Recommendation

As the behavior of `N-B.y` and `N-B.x` is different from `B` or `(!\psGetNodeCenter{B} B.y B.x)`, it is better to avoid using `N-B.y` and `N-B.x`. They are confusing!