# Redefining some of predefined styles in tikzstyle?

Tags: tikz-styles

In the following example, how can I redefine one property of the predefined `block` style in the `tikzpicture` environment without affecting the others:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
        \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw,minimum width=3em,]
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture} % This works ok
   \node[block, minimum width=3em,] (b1) {B1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={minimum width=3em,}] % This reset all styles
   \node[block] (b1) {B1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the handler `.append style`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
        \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw,minimum width=3em,]
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture} % This works ok
   \node[block, minimum width=3em,] (b1) {B1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[block/.append style={minimum width=10em,}] %
   \node[block] (b1) {B1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! I have to say that `tikz`/`pgfplots` should be awarded the *Most Confusing Syntax Award*.

Comment: @jak123 It seems like you never tried using `pstricks`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Is it worse?

Comment: @jak123 It is super inconsistent, cf. [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64236/10995).