# Bit string diagram with LaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am interested to make some diagrams like the sample picture. I am not sure whether it can be done using Latex or not. Can anybody give any idea. Thanks.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: It certainly *can* if you don't mind the time and the learning curve. Take a look at [TikZ](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) and [PS Tricks](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pst-user.pdf). Also, there's a nice comparison of the two here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6676/what-are-the-advantages-of-tikz-pgf-over-pstricks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For starting point in your learning (in case that as basic tool you select TikZ package) can serve the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=0pt,
 start chain = A going right,
    X/.style = {rectangle, draw,% styles of nodes in string (chain)
                minimum width=2ex, minimum height=3ex,
                outer sep=0pt, on chain},
    B/.style = {decorate,
                decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt,
                pre=moveto,pre length=1pt,post=moveto,post length=1pt,
                raise=1mm,
                            #1}, % for mirroring of brace, if necessary
                thick},
    B/.default=mirror, % by default braces are mirrored
                        ]
\foreach \i in {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,
                0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0}% <-- content of nodes
    \node[X] {\i};
\draw[B] ( A-1.south west) -- node[below=2mm] {Channel 1 Links} ( A-9.south east);
\draw[B] (A-10.south west) -- node[below=2mm] {Channel 2 Links} (A-18.south east);
\draw[B] (A-19.south west) -- node[below=2mm] {Channel 3 Links} (A-27.south east);
\node (B1) [inner sep=1pt,above=of A-10.north west] {$\times$};
\node (B2) [inner sep=1pt,above=of A-19.north west] {$\times$};
\draw[B=](B1.north) -- node[above=2mm] {Crossover Points}(B2.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Short explanation of code:**
Above code is (very) concise, so for it understanding some experience with TikZ package is necessary. In it design I considered the following:

- The simple structure of picture. It has 27 nodes with equal shapes which form a chain. Therefore the `chains` library from TikZ is used for their positioning. It is defined by option `start chain = A going right`, where A is chain name. Consequently nodes in chain are named A-1, A-2, ... , A-27.
- Distances between nodes in chain is determined by `node distance`. Its default value is 15 mm, so with `node distance=0pt` it is set to zero, so nodes are separated only by `outer sep` parameter of shapes. That border lines are properly overlapped, also this distance is set to zero (in definition of nodes' style, it is named X)
- In the TikZ the `foreach` loops is intended to do repeating task. Such task is setting nodes in chain. with

  `\forach \i in {...}\node[X] {\i};`

  are formed a chain of nodes (with style X), with content determined by list in curly braces. Since their positions are determined by chain, the loop actually only determine their number and content.
- Braces below and above nodes is drawn by use of
  `decorations.pathreplacing` library. In it definition among their
  parameters the parameter `mirror` is select as free parameter which
  is can be determined later. Since the three from four braces are
  mirrored, this is set as default and exception is determined
  "locally".
- Braces is designed so, that they are `1pt` shorter on each side than
  is distance between coordinates, and with `raise=1mm` is move below (when is
  mirrored) or above (when is not mirrored) from given coordinates.
- The crosses above begin and end of "channel 2 links" is set on
  "classic way" with `above=of <coordinate name>` and for it is used
  math symbol for multiplying.

More deep description of principle of TikZ which are used heree is in TikZ manual:

- for chains: chapter 46 Chains, page 541
- for `\foreach` loop: chapter 83 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement, page 901
- for braces: subsection 48.3 Path Replacing Decorations, page 581

Comment: would you be willing to annotate that code a bit?  For example, is the code from `node distance` through the `\foreach` loop all one command?

Comment: I will, very soon :-)

Answer (score 9):

A short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

 \begin{pspicture}
  \psset{dimen=middle, linewidth=0.6pt, braceWidthOuter=4pt, braceWidthInner=4pt, braceWidth=0.8pt, labelsep =-2ex}
  \multido{\i = 0 + 1, \n=0+0.5}{27}{\fnode[framesize=0.5](\n, 0){A\i}}%
  \rmultiput{$0$}(A0)(A3)(A4)(A5)(A7)(A8)(A9)(A11)(A13)(A14)(A15)(A17)(A18)(A19)(A22)(A23)(A25)(A26)
  \rmultiput{$1$}(A1)(A2)(A6)(A10)(A12)(A16)(A20)(A21)(A24)
  \psset{rot=90, nodesepB=2ex}
  \multido{\ia=0 + 9, \ib=8 + 9}{3}{\pnode[-0.15, -0.35](A\ia){B\ia}\pnode[0.15, -0.35](A\ib){B\ib}\psbrace(B\ia)(B\ib){\clap{Channel\,1 Links}}}
  \multido{\i=8 + 9}{2}{\pnode[0.25,0.6](A\i){C\i}\uput{1pt}[d](C\i){$\times$}}
  \psbrace[rot=-90, nodesepB=-0.5ex](C17)(C8){\clap{Crossover Points}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]