# Advantages of using Sketch?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, sketch

I was wondering what the advantage of using [Sketch](http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net/) is over TiKz or PStricks other than projection planes and transparency effects? I feel as though TiKz can do all the features that Sketch provides and using Sketch just clutters my LaTeX editing workflow

Comment: This feels like an opinion-based question. Objective comparisons (e.g. one answer per tool with some reasonably predictable list of criteria) can be OK, but there is no real answer to 'is X better than Y'.

Comment: I quote "New Tikz/PGF support. In addition to PSTricks, sketch now understands TikZ/PGF options (key/value pairs) and generates TikZ output. Advantages are that TikZ works directly with pdfLaTeX and supports transparency."

Comment: @JosephWright I was wondering what were the advantages not which one was better

Comment: @AndréC those are the advantages of using TiKz over PStricks

Comment: I've never used pstricks before, so I can't really say. I've heard that the difference is that TikZ is compileable with all engines but pstricks offers possibilities that TikZ doesn't offer, so....

Comment: @AndréC The OP was to compare SKETCH with TikZ or PStricks as opposed to comparing TiKz and PStricks which is provided in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6676/what-are-the-advantages-of-tikz-pgf-over-pstricks?rq=1

Comment: Reading the manual, an obvious potentially huge limitation is that Sketch can't draw smooth curves, and can't do geometry on smooth curved surfaces. It doesn't even know what a circle is. But of course that is only a limitation if you want to draw circles!

Comment: I guess there might be a wording issue. You are asking about the "advantage of using Sketch is over TiKz or PStricks", which reads a bit like you want to use Setch instead of Ti*k*Z or PSTricks. However, Sketch seems to produce Ti*k*Z or PSTricks code, so this interpretation is maybe not what you want to know. How about you ask about nice examples of pictures produced using Sketch, and then everybody reading the answers can decide themselves whether or not there is a point using it?

Comment: The question was driven by one of the responses in the LaTeX showcase question here on stackexchange, the italian aviation document. In that document a lot of the diagrams were very detailed and good and drawn using Sketch. I was wondering why someone would use Sketch over TiKz because to me it appears as though TiKz can do most of the things that Sketch do

Comment: SolidWorks is the king.

Comment: @AndréC: Every tool supports transparency ...

Comment: @Herbert I only copied and pasted the Sketch homepage. [Free Graphics Software for the TeX, LaTeX, and PSTricks Community](http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net)

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy isn't SolidWorks a paid application? Also it does not really relate to the question at all...

Comment: @AndréC: That informations are from the last century!

Comment: @Herbert I suggest that you answer the question since my quotes are those of the link given by the question and obviously the person who asked the question did not realize that this link is 6 years old or that his information is false.

Comment: @AndréC I feel as though you have interpreted the words on the website incorrectly. Sketch supported PStricks before but now with support for TikZ and TikZ is able to work with pdflatex. That is why it says that TikZ has this advantage over PStricks but as mentioned earlier there is already another question discussing this. My question is asking what advantage does SKETCH have over TikZ and PStricks as opposed to what advantage does TikZ have over PStricks? If you are referring to something else that is false please let me know

Comment: @AndréC I don't believe that the age of the information is relevant when answering the question, for many LaTeX packages are quite old. Herbert and I are making the point that the information that you provided is not relevant to the question and is comparing TikZ and PStricks, although PStricks has gotten significantly better since then and now supports transperancy. Please look for relevant information before copy pasting anything that has advantages, for if it was on the homepage I would not have posted this question.

Comment: I didn't interpret anything at all, I made a quote from the Sketch homepage that @Herbert disputes.

Comment: The age of the information on the Sketch homepage was raised by @Herbert. I only answered him.

Comment: @AndréC my point is that the information you copy pasted is not relevant as it compares two other things that is already questioned in another post

Comment: @AndréC next time please try an interpret the information and see if it has any significance before copy pasting it into a discussion. If it were on the homepage I would never have made this post...

Comment: I'm sorry I can't read the crystal balls to see if you've read this page or not.  As for the other post, I don't know what you're talking about either.

Comment: I think I am having trouble communicating with you @AndréC, I am saying your information is not helpful and if you would like to contribute find something else which is actually relevant to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88292/discussion-between-andrec-and-sab-hoque).